# Python: sharing message between processes

Tags: python, class, process, message, synchronize

I've been searching for answer to that problem for few hours but couldn't solve it so I have to post here this question, I'm sure it's trivial.

The project I work with has many classes and threads and I'm adding small classes to it. Those classes are executed in different threads with project's engine but I need them to synchronize between themselves - that is class A should be able to send a message to class B. They are also in different modules.

**EDIT2: there is a new explanation of this question: look at the bottom.**

I am really very beginner in python and I tried to solve this by sharing queue object (Queue.Queue()) and examining it's content in endless loops, I made very simple module with this object and methods get and put:

messenger module:

```
import Queue

MessageQueue = Queue.Queue()

def GetMessage():
    return MessageQueue.get()

def PutMessage(message):
    MessageQueue.put(message)
    return
```

and use it in two different classes (import messenger), but since it's not global variable, I assume that 'MessageQueue' object has different instances in different classes. Because those classes seems working on different queues.

How to synchronize two classes with such object between (maybe there is a pretier way instead just making this queue global)?

**EDIT1 - here are classes:**

class A:

```
from utils import messenger as m

class Foo():

[...]

def foo():

    [...]
    m.put(message)
```

class B:

```
from utils import messenger

class Bar():

[...]

def bar():

    [...]
    while True:           
       print(str(m.get()))
```

**EDIT2: Since I understand my problem a bit better now, here is an update:**

Both classes are run as distinct programs in different processes (what may explain why the are not sharing global variables :)).

So the problem remains: how to synchronize between two different programs? The only solution I think of is to make a file on a disc and read it between processes, but it seems very unreliable (locks etc.) and slow.

Can you suggest me different approach?

Comment: Did you make an actual class or just a module?

Comment: You haven't shown us any class here; you've just got a global variable and two global functions. So, either this is not the code you're asking about, or you don't mean the same thing by "global variable" that most people do.

Comment: @Blender: yes, I made a module only - i corrected question (it's not third class, it's just a module)

Comment: Then your question doesn't make any sense. You _do_ have a global variable, which everyone shares, so… everyone shares it.

Comment: but it didn't work... class A puts messages and B is freezed, waiting for msg - you are sure it should work even in different threads?

Comment: You haven't shown us where `m` is defined, and that's the part that matters. If, say, each module has a separate global variable `m`, then two objects defined in different modules will see different `m` variables. The way around that is to put a single `m` in some module they can both access, and use `somemodule.m`.

Comment: @abarnert: acutally, I made a typo, 'm' is just an alias of messenger (import messenger as m). I tried to make this somemodule, but after i'm importing it both classes end up with different queues instead of the same one.

Comment: What you've actually posted here has a number of almost-certainly-unrelated problems, and isn't a runnable example. If I make a trivial runnable example, like [this](http://pastebin.com/xQrwaW1E), it works. So, there is obviously something wrong with your code—maybe a simple typo, maybe a deep problem with your threading model, who knows—but it's not in what you've described or shown here. In particular, using a global queue this way works fine. So… I'm not sure what anyone can do for you, unless you can create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @abarnet, thank you for this example! It works indeed (i just had to get rid of argument in foo()), so I checked and it seems files 'a' and 'b' are run in different python procesess. I printed addresses of queues, and those are different objects, but since they are in different processes that's understandable. Sorry for this confused explanation, but I'm still new at this :).

So, the problem remains - I tried to run your classes in different python interpreters and - of course - both classes have different object of queue.

How to synchronize classes between different python instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem using [Zero MQ](http://zeromq.org) library.

**Node A, the publisher:**

```
import zmq, time
from datetime import datetime

context = zmq.Context()

#create this node as publisher
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://*:25647")


for i in range(300):
   message = ("%d, %d" % (1, i))
   print str(datetime.now().time()) + "> sending: " + message
   socket.send(message)
   time.sleep(1)
```

**Node B, the receiver:**

```
import zmq, time
from datetime import datetime

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:25647")

#filter message for particular subscriber ('1')
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '1')

while True:
    message = socket.recv()
    print(str(datetime.now().time()) + "> received: " + str(message))
```

This setting does what I wanted, that is, it conveys signal from one program to another and it does it in quite good time (this very simple message, tuple of two integers, is sent in around 0.5 ms).

Two important things:

1. subscribe have to be "authorized" to receive message - it is done by filtering the first value of message
2. publisher is "binding", subscriber "connecting" to socket

Answer (score 0):

The way to share any object among multiple instances (of different classes, of the same class, whatever) without making it global is the same: Pass the object into each instance's constructor. For example:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, m):
        self.m = m
        # ...

    # ...

    def foo(self):
        # ...
        self.m.put(message)
        # ...

# ...

class Bar(object):

    def __init__(self, m):
        self.m = m
        self.foo = Foo(m)
        # ...

    # ...

    def foo(self):
        # ...
        self.m.put(message)
        # ...

# ...

m = Queue.Queue()
bar1 = Bar(m)
bar2 = Bar(m)
```

Now `bar1`, `bar2`, `bar1.foo`, and `bar2.foo` all have the same `m` object.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The problem is, I'm a bit lost in this project as it is big and has multiple inherited classes within different modules, and there is no simple way to just find place where bar1 and bar2 are instantiated - because it's spread all over code, and I can't even make changes so deep in code. Therefore I thought to just add another module to those modules into classes Foo and Bar, and try not to interfere with constructors.

Comment: I thought that object imported through "import" keyword can be seen as global variable, but instead I have two different queues (they are in different threads I think, that's why).

Comment: For your first question: I may have over-complicated my explanation. So let me make it even more complicated. :) A global is global _to a specific module_. But, unless you do something tricky and bad (e.g., run code from the middle of a package directory), every `import foo` will end up referencing the exact same `foo` module. So, on the one hand, each separate `foo` module has a different copy of the globals… but (again, unless you do something tricky) there is only one such `foo` module, so there's only one copy of the globals, so everyone shares, so everything is fine.

Comment: For your second question: Being in different threads does not cause them to get different globals. (Unless you use `threading.local`, which I'm sure you're not doing.) So, that can't be the problem. Of course any shared globals have to be properly synchronized, but the whole point of `queue.Queue` is that it's _automatically_ properly synchronized, without you having to do anything. So, that can't be your problem either.